# At least one of your app or app bundles contain an actions.xml file

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-build

All of sudden google console started throwing an error message saying - "At least one of your app or app bundles contain an actions.xml file."

I have searched my entire app, there is no actions.xml.
Also used Analyze Apk tool of android studio to cross verify if any lib or other module may adding the actions.xml.

Here is one troubleshoot link from google ([link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/troubleshoot#error_4)) it describe the process To accept the Actions on Google Terms of Service.

But question remains the same that project doesn't contain any actions.xml.

Is it a console bug or I am missing anything.

Comment: Do you have an <action> schema in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: found any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was very weird but when I tried to upload the apk after sometime it worked perfectly fine without any error messages.

As I rightly mentioned in the question there was no action.xml and action tag anywhere in my entire project.

It seems to be a console bug in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It *was* a Google Play Console bug:

> Thanks for your patience while our team investigated the behavior you experienced.
>
> They have recently made some changes that should fix the problem. With the recent set of changes, please check to see if you are still experiencing the same issue. If so, I will be happy to see how else we can help.
>
> Please ensure to clear your browser's cache and cookies first using the instructions available in our help center before accessing the Play Console again.